# how to pass name of a logged in user to each and every jsp page

Tags: jsp

How to pass  name of a logged in user to each and every jsp page. I am not able to get it in each and every page.please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Read the link- http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp

Comment: can u help me  with any sites, or jus tel me how to achieve this.

Comment: i am not gettting .. please help.. i am posting my code below.

Answer (score 0):

can you post some code ? if you are using servlets, take it from the login form with request.getParameter("attribute name") and store on the session.

```
request.getSession.setAttribute("current-user",request.getParameter("attribute name"));
```

now, your username will be available as ${sessionScope.current-user} on every page.